# Progam isnt importing variables from py file after converting to an exe

Tags: python-3.x, exe

I have been creating a python game for school and need to convert the program into an .exe file to hand in. My code imports all of the variable from separate .py file. It also saves the files using f.write to write in all the variables. This works completely fine when using visual studio. However after I've converted the program into the .exe it stopped working. After saving the variables in my game, the variables are written in and I can see this by opening up the file separately in visual studio. But the files do not take effect when playing the game and it runs normally as if the variables weren't in the file.

```
from save0 import * #Holds the 'savefile' variable
if savefile == "save1.py": #Checks what file the user is using imports variables from that file.
    from save1 import *
    print("you are using save 1") 
    os.system("pause")
if savefile == "save2.py":
    print("you are using save 2")
    os.system("pause")
    from save2 import *
if savefile == "save3.py":
    print("you are using save 3")
    os.system("pause")
    from save3 import *
if savefile == "save4.py":
    print("you are using save 4")
    os.system("pause")
    from save4 import *
if savefile == "save5.py":
    print("you are using save 5")
    os.system("pause")
    from save5 import *
```

This is the code i am using to handle the importing of variables but i cant seem to figure out what is wrong. I don't really understand how the program runs based off of a seemingly default set of variables when it should be reading a altered set of variables.

I have confirmed that the file is importing the expected file, or should be. I am honestly not sure what else to write and have been kind of stuck on this problem for a while. It shows no errors. I've also tried changing the way I've converted it in the autopytoexe converter. Sorry for any information i have left out i tried to outline the problem to the best of my abilities. Thanks for any possible help.

Comment: Programs like autopytoexe will only include files imported in your code, so the `save0.py` file will be bundled with the executable but the rest of them won't be included (at least that's what I'm assuming since they are imported conditionally). If this is case, adding `import save1, save2, ` ect might include the files automatically, but if that doesn't work then you will want to use the `additional files` option to manually put the files in with the rest of you program.

Comment: Unfortunately neither worked. The project is due tomorrow and the saving feature isn't necessary so I'm just going to bite the bullet and remove it. Thanks for the help anyway.